# How to get mean and std from a dictionary of dataframe per each key

Tags: python, performance, dictionary, transformation, transpose

Here is my dilemma:

I got a dictionary of dataframes like this:

```
dict_df[key]

m1      m2  m3  m4  m5  m6  
10410   5   10  21  33  11
15387   3   10  33  45  13
19026   4   16  27  40  11
26083   5   21  16  29  9
27806   4   17  23  31  7
43820   2   12  27  40  18
49199   7   22  30  38  11
50094   4   9   13  18  4
```

Per each key, it returns a DF with the same column names.

For each key, I need to store the mean and standard deviation of a set of features (let's take for example m2, m3, m4).

In the end, I want to obtain something like this df below (the numbers are totally random):

```
key   m2_mean    m2_std   m3_mean   m3_std    m4_mean     m4_std
key1    12       55         793      438       44           95
key2    14       442        21       43        14           442
key3    44       1          66       11        42           42
key4    42       42         2        23        98           70
```

The dataset is not that big, so even if the code is slow should be fine.

Thanks for the help and have a good one!

Comment: Can you show us the code you tried? And exactly where are you stuck?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, let's define some sample data:

```
>>> df1 = pd.DataFrame({
        "col1": [1, 2, 3],
        "col2": [4, 5, 6],
    })
>>> df2 = pd.DataFrame({
        "col1": [7, 8, 9],
        "col2": [10, 11, 12],
    })
>>> dict_df = {
        "df1": df1,
        "df2": df2,
    }
```

Now, you can use `.agg()` to calculate the mean and std of your dataframe (I've used max for simplicity), `.stack()` to reduce the dataframe into a single series, and `.to_dict()` to generate a representation of this result as a string. Notice that we'll only use one of the dataframes (`df1`) to show this result:

```
>>> df1.agg(["mean", "max"]).stack().to_dict()
{('mean', 'col1'): 2.0, ('mean', 'col2'): 5.0, ('max', 'col1'): 3.0, ('max', 'col2'): 6.0}
```

With this dict representation, we can use `pd.DataFrame.from_dict` to build a single dataframe with the metrics for each value in `dict_df`:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({
        df_name: df[["col1", "col2"]].agg(["mean", "max"]).stack().to_dict()
        for df_name, df in dict_df.items()
    }, orient="index")
>>> df
    mean        max      
    col1  col2 col1  col2
df1  2.0   5.0  3.0   6.0
df2  8.0  11.0  9.0  12.0
```

The only important difference with your expected output is in the column names, but we can solve that manually:

```
>>> df.columns = ["_".join(column) for column in df.columns]
>>> df
     mean_col1  mean_col2  max_col1  max_col2
df1        2.0        5.0       3.0       6.0
df2        8.0       11.0       9.0      12.0
```

---

Code that would do the trick for you:

```
>>> target_columns = ["m2", "m3", "m4"]
>>> df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({
        key: df[target_columns].agg(["mean", "std"]).stack().to_dict()
        for key, df in dict_df.items()
    }, orient="index")
>>> df.columns = ["_".join(column) for column in df.columns]
>>> df.index.name = "key"
```

Answer (score 1):

Start with creating a dictionary for the aggregates, in the form of `new_col_name: (dataframe_column_name, aggregare_function)`:

```py
required_aggs = {f'{col_name}_{agg_name}': (col_name, agg_name)
                 for agg_name in ['mean', 'std']
                 for col_name in df}
```

Above gives following dictionary of the required aggregates, and the column names.

```py
{
    'm1_mean': ('m1', 'mean'),
    'm1_std': ('m1', 'std'),
    'm2_mean': ('m2', 'mean'),
    'm2_std': ('m2', 'std'),
    'm3_mean': ('m3', 'mean'),
    'm3_std': ('m3', 'std'),
    'm4_mean': ('m4', 'mean'),
    'm4_std': ('m4', 'std'),
    'm5_mean': ('m5', 'mean'),
    'm5_std': ('m5', 'std'),
    'm6_mean': ('m6', 'mean'),
    'm6_std': ('m6', 'std')
}
```

Now, for each dataframe, assign the key column with the value of the key, then group by this column, and call `.agg` on groupby object passing unpacked version of above aggregate dictionary:

```py
>>> df.assign(key=123).groupby('key').agg(**required_aggs)

       m1_mean  m2_mean  m3_mean  ...    m4_std    m5_std    m6_std
key                               ...                              
123  30228.125     4.25   14.625  ...  6.860862  8.447316  4.140393
```

**PS:** In above snippet, df is a single dataframe in `dict_df[key]`, and value of this `key` is assumed to be `123`. You need to do the same for each dataframes in the dictionary. Also, if you need to calculate aggregate of specific columns only, you just need to replace `df` in `for col_name in df` by list of columns e.g.: `for col_name in ['m1', 'm2']`

Comment: why do you use GroupBy.agg instead of  DataFrame.agg?